# Stetho is not working in chrome Version 89.0.4389.72 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Tags: stetho

Just getting blank screen for all(Network calls,Elements, Sources, timeline, Profiles, Resources, Audit, Console), is there any way to fix this???

Comment: I have the same issue as of today. Do you have a solution?

Comment: I also encounter this issue. For the moment I use Microsoft edge dev tools (`edge://inspect`) instead of chrome dev tools to monitor networks from stetho

Answer (score 1):

Yes, downgrade the chrome version to privious version

Answer (score 1):

I tried on Version 89.0.4389.90 (Official Build) (x86_64) and faced the same issue , but was able to use it as expected when I downgraded to 88.0.4324.192 (Official Build) (x86_64). I would recommend to downgrade to this version.

Answer (score 0):

As a variant you can try Microsoft Edge that works well now with Stetho.
I found it yeasterday and it made my day! Stetho is a great tool and I don't need to think anymore how to make Chrome to work with it!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29907411)